# Issue with visual studio build agent behind a proxy

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I am currently setting up continuous integration using Visual Studio Team Services with onsite build agents, but I am having issues with my company's proxy.

I have tried adding the [.proxy file](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v2-windows#web_proxy) but my company's proxy is still blocking it (it is a very old proxy).

Speaking to my infrastructure guys they can bypass the proxy but need all the urls that the build agent calls.

Unfortunately I can not find a list online of all the urls that it requires, I know it needs the following:

- https://xxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com
- https://xxxxxxxxx.vssps.visualstudio.com

Does anyone know all the other urls that an onsite build agent calls?

Comment: When adding the .proxy file, did you also set the system level environment variables with the username+password so that the agent can authenticate? And which version of the agent are you using, the 1.x or the 2.x version?

Comment: I have granted premissions to the user that the agent runs under for proxy authentication. I am using 2.110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell, the agent itself uses a number of URI's connect, the ones I know of are these at least:

- *account*.visualstudio.com
- *account*.vsrm.visualstudio.com
- *account*.vssps.visualstudio.com
- app.vssps.visualstudio.com

But then there are a number of tasks that need download access as well, e.g.

- npm needs access to www.npmjs.com
- Sonar Qube needs to download the sonar runner
- NuGet needs access to www.nuget.org to restore packages
- ...

Then depending on which extensions you use, you may need additional ones

- My Snyk task needs access to snyk.io for example

The easiest way to find them all is to setup a build agent outside of your company network and monitor the traffic with fiddler. To get an answer from the source I recommend to post an issue [on the vsts-agent github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues).

Comment: Perfect thank you, I have just posted an issue on there. if anyone else is interested here is the issue link https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/726